# Making existing user an Admin on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-admin

I have installed rails_admin to my rails 3 app which I have set up to authenticate admins based on an "admin" field I added to my User model. Is there a simple way to make an existing user on my Heroku install an admin? I cannot perform SQL on the database because I am currently on a shared DB. Would creating a migration that sets a user(s) as admin be the way to go? Seems kind of like a hack...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `heroku console` (or `heroku run rails console` if you're on their new Cedar stack). It's just like `rails console` locally, and should allow you to easily make this change.

Comment: Duh. For some reason I was thinking Heroku didn't have console access. Thanks!

Comment: Duh me too. Guess I didn't fully understand what you were trying to do. Thought you were asking about architecture. lol. Glad you got your answer

Answer (score 1):

Broken down step by step:

`heroku run rails c`

`User.find(55)` or any other id that matches the user you want. If It's the only user, `User.first` will suffice.

`user = User.admin = true` assuming you have an admin column of type boolean.

`user.save`

`ctrl + c` to exit the console

Comment: user= User.find(55)     user.admin=true    user.save   worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a specific type of user, I would use the Rails STI to manage the different user types. Your user.rb still has all your validation on user creating and some permissions, but you would have a

normal_user.rb

```
class NormalUser < User
end
```

admin_user.rb

```
class AdminUser < User
end
```

Your migration would be to add 'type' to the users table. Then any existing user you wanted to make an admin you would just find and set their type to 'AdminUser'. Any admin specific actions you need, you can just use

```
User.is_a?(AdminUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to create admin on production:

1. add admin user in `seed.rb` file and run it on production. Command to run seed file on heroku:

   heroku run rake db:seed
2. open `heroku run rails console` which open console on heroku cloud and you can create user/admin manually.